# Cannot watch an array ref in Vue 3

Tags: vuejs3

I'm building a scroller with dynamic elements. I want to be able to scroll to a certain `Entry` for some conditions, but first the underlying `entries` have to be populated and I choose to put `ref`'s on them and watch as the array gets filled. But the problem is, the watcher never triggers.

What's wrong with this?

```js
<script setup>
// ...imports

const entries = ref([]); // This gets populated properly.
const entryComponentsRefs = ref([]);

// This doesn't trigger
watch(entryComponentRefs, (value) => {
  console.log(value);

  value.forEach(e => {
    console.log(e.root)
  });
});

onMounted(async () => {
  entries.value = await fetchEntries()
});
</script>

<template>
  <Container>
    <Entry v-for="entry in entries" :key="entry.id" ref="entryComponentsRefs" />
    <!-- <Entry> component has its root element exposed as `root` -->
  </Container>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Vue's documentation is really good sometimes I prefer to refer to Vue's source code.

In our case we should watch our DOM element array deep so we could catch items being added, removed and updated.

So if we check `watch` we can see that watching a ref isn't deep, deep watching works only with reactive variables:

```
function doWatch(source, cb, { immediate, deep, flush, onTrack, onTrigger } = EMPTY_OBJ) {

  ...

  let getter;
  let forceTrigger = false;
  let isMultiSource = false;
  if (isRef(source)) {
    getter = () => source.value; // only watches value of `value` no deep watching
    forceTrigger = isShallow(source);
  } else if (isReactive(source)) { // deep watching is default with reactive objects
    getter = () => source;
    deep = true;
```

Fortunately any object variable including arrays becomes reactive when initialized/assigned to a ref, so we just can use it directly:

```
watch(entryComponentRefs.value, (value) => {
  console.log(value);

  value.forEach(e => {
    console.log(e.root)
  });
});
```

Also we could force deep watching with `{deep: true}`:

```
watch(entryComponentRefs, (value) => {
  console.log(value);

  value.forEach(e => {
    console.log(e.root)
  });
}, {deep: true});
```

**BUT WE HAVE A PROBLEM WITH THE DESIGN PATTERN:**

There are several reason why watching DOM ref isn't a good design pattern.

- Virtual DOM discourages manipulating and accessing DOM directly
- Logic based on DOM changes rather than on data changes is an anti-pattern in MV.. frameworks
- Watching a DOM ref is buggy in our case (see below)

Fortunately Vue has a dedicated way to access an updated DOM when the underlying data is changed. If you add the `{flush: 'post'}` option, you can access the updated DOM inside a watch callback:

```
watch(entries, () => {
  // access your updated entryComponentsRefs here
}, {flush: 'post'});
```

[Vue3 SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

And about the bug. For some reason `watch(entryComponentRefs.value, ...)` triggers the callback twice, which I would consider a bad behavior since in reality the underlying `entries` array is updated only once. I digged into the source code, seems the problem that an additional Vue job is created during the watch's triggering and flushed. That calls the callback again. I guess I need to report this to the Vue's issues in the github.

So using `watch(entries, ..., {flush: 'post'})` is a safer way to go.