# Why isn't scrollIntoView working within Vue watcher to automatically scroll to new messages in chat app?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am learning how to build chat apps in Vue 3. One thing I am confused about is why the app example I made does not automatically scroll to the bottom of the screen when a new message appears (a common experience in chat apps).

**Anyone know why when a new message is loaded, the browser does not automatically  scroll the user down to the bottom of the screen despite my `scrollIntoView` method?** It "works" when I manually click the "Scroll" button at the top of the page, but for some reason the Watcher is not able to do it.

Here's my code:
[Vue SFC playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

```
<template>
  <section>
    <button @click="scrollToElement()">Scroll</button>
    <ul ref="chatContainer">
      <li v-for="message in messages" :key="message.id">
        {{ message.title }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</template>

<script setup>
import { onMounted, ref, watch } from 'vue'

const chatContainer = ref(null)
const messages = ref([])

const fetchChatMessages = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  const messagesArr = await response.json()
  messages.value = messagesArr
}

const addNewMessage = () => {
  // Simulate a new message and add it to the chat
  const newMessage = {
    userId: 1,
    id: messages.value.length + 1,
    title: 'New Message',
    body: 'This is a new chat message.'
  }
  messages.value.push(newMessage)
}

const scrollToElement = () => {
  const el = chatContainer.value
  el.scrollIntoView({ block: 'end', behavior: 'smooth' })
}

watch(messages, () => {
  if (chatContainer.value) {
    scrollToElement()
  }
}, {
  immediate: true
})

onMounted(async () => {
  await fetchChatMessages()

  setInterval(() => {
    addNewMessage()
  }, 1000)
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`messages` is a ref and unfortunately a ref doesn't deep watch objects. That's actually misleading, I even created an issue: https://github.com/vuejs/docs/issues/2454#issuecomment-1783779632

But you don't need to deep watch your messages since it's expensive, just use a callback watch:

```
watch(() => messages.value.length, () => {
  if (chatContainer.value) {
    scrollToElement()
  }
}, {
  immediate: true
})
```

A more detailed explanation of the problem is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76786671/14098260

Comment: Nice tip! I was also confused about the `implicitly create`... comment.

Answer (score 1):

You need a [deep watcher](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#deep-watchers) for watching nested objects and arrays:

```js
watch(messages, () => {
  if (chatContainer.value) {
    scrollToElement()
  }
}, {
  immediate: true,
  deep: true
})
```